# Hash map array list to JSON array in android?

Tags: android, json

```
"order_item" : [{"price":"250.00","product_code":"1","quantity":"2","
total":"500.00"},
{"price":"200.00","product_**code":"2","quantity":"1","**total":"200.00"} ]
}
```

I have to convert my hash map array list into above json array format.In my first position of array list i have sets like price=250.00,product_code=1,quantity=2,total:500.00,in my second position price=60.00,product_code=55,quantity=10,total:600.00 and so on.Any of them know answer help me.

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson(); String json = gson.toJson(YourHashMaphere); System.out.println("json = " + json); Go to this link for More information :[Guide To JSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) . it might help you

Comment: This is my array list values : [{item_quantity=2, item_nmae=Chargrilled vegetable salad, Product_id=17, item_price=100, Total=200, avaliable_quantity=12}, {item_quantity=1, item_nmae=Mushroom Soup, Product_id=12, item_price=120, Total=120, avaliable_quantity=28}]

Comment: and tryied like this for(int i=0;i<alist.size();i++) {
    
             alist_item.put("product_code",""+alist.get(i).get(PRODUCT_ID));
             //Log.d("jSON", ""+alist.get(i).get(PRODUCT_ID));
             alist_item.put("quantity", ""+alist.get(i).get(ITEM_QUANTITY_COLUMN));
             alist_item.put("price",""+alist.get(i).get(ITEM_PRICE_COLUMN));
             alist_item.put("total",""+alist.get(i).get(TOTAL_COLUMN));
             jsonArray.put(alist_item); 
             
   }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class Product 
{
   private String price;

   private String product_code;

   private String quantity;

   private int total;

   public Product(String price, String product_code, String quantity, int total)
   {
      this.price = price;
      this.product_code = product_code;
      this.quantity = quantity;
      this.total = total;
   }
}
```

business logic

```
new Gson().toJson(map);
```

usage

```
      Product pr1 = new Product("str1", "str1", "str1", 250);
      Product pr2 = new Product("str2", "str2", "str2", 200);
      List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
      list.add(pr1);
      list.add(pr2);
      Map<String, List<Product>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Product>>();
      map.put("order_item", list);

      System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(map));
```

**EDIT** (using [json.org](http://json.org))

```
      Map<String, String> jsonMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
      jsonMap1.put("price", "250.00");
      jsonMap1.put("product_code", "1");
      jsonMap1.put("quantity", "2");
      jsonMap1.put("total", "200");
      Map<String, String> jsonMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
      jsonMap2.put("price", "250.00");
      jsonMap2.put("product_code", "1");
      jsonMap2.put("quantity", "2");
      jsonMap2.put("total", "200");

      JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(jsonMap1);
      JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(jsonMap2);

      JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
      array.put(json1);
      array.put(json2);

      JSONObject finalObject = new JSONObject();
      finalObject.put("order_item", array);

      System.out.println(finalObject.toString());
```

**EDIT2** (using Gson)

```
      Map<String, String> jsonMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
      jsonMap1.put("price", "250.00");
      jsonMap1.put("product_code", "1");
      jsonMap1.put("quantity", "2");
      jsonMap1.put("total", "200");
      Map<String, String> jsonMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
      jsonMap2.put("price", "250.00");
      jsonMap2.put("product_code", "1");
      jsonMap2.put("quantity", "2");
      jsonMap2.put("total", "200");
      List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
      list.add(jsonMap1);
      list.add(jsonMap2);
      Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Map<String, String>>>();
      map.put("order_item", list);

      System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(map));
```

Comment: in side my array list like this price=250.00,product_code=1,quantity=2,total:500.00

Comment: @yugesh what type has *this*? Is it *String*?

Comment: ashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
      map.put(PRODUCT_ID, ""+Submenu_id);
      map.put(ITEM_AVALIABLE_QUANTITY, ""+item_quantity);
      map.put(ITEM_NAME_COLUMN,""+item_name);
      map.put(ITEM_PRICE_COLUMN,"" + item_price);
      map.put(ITEM_QUANTITY_COLUMN, "" + quantity);
      map.put(TOTAL_COLUMN, "" + Total);
 alist.add(map);

Comment: This is my array list values llya : [{item_quantity=2, item_nmae=Chargrilled vegetable salad, Product_id=17, item_price=100, Total=200, avaliable_quantity=12}, {item_quantity=1, item_nmae=Mushroom Soup, Product_id=12, item_price=120, Total=120, avaliable_quantity=28}]

Comment: k i tried and say.i got one thing to convert array list using gson its just automatically convert the array list to json array list llya

Comment: llya thank u so much i got the answer.u save my time.once again thank u llya,,,:)

Comment: @Ilya  thanks for best tutorial  just missing is Gson jar:( I downloaded and added now problem is solved :) +1:)

Comment: @Ilya did you try with gson my order is changing again. Can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429017/json-object-item-order

Comment: @llya do you know how to achieve the same with jackson or moxy..can you help me