# Json Object Item Order

Tags: java, json, jsp

I have written some code;

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
     try {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rslt.getMetaData();
        while ( rslt.next() ){
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
            LinkedHashMap<String, String> jsonOrderedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < metaData.getColumnCount(); i++){
                jsonOrderedMap.put(metaData.getColumnName(i+1), rslt.getString(i+1) );
            }
            System.out.println(jsonOrderedMap);
            /* This doesn't work */
            ja.put(jsonOrderedMap);
            //System.out.println(ja);

        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

I'am tring to order my json object ( I know it is not supposed to ordered , but I need it) It works until when I try to put my jsonOrderedMap to json array. Before JsonArray, json object looks like this :

```
{CUSTOMER_SECTOR_ID=611, CUSTOMER_NO=0013114193, CUSTOMER_NAME=asdfasdfds}
```

After putting some jsonOrderedMap to jsonArray, It looks like this;

```
[{"CUSTOMER_NAME":"qweqwe","CUSTOMER_NO":"0000003124","CUSTOMER_SECTOR_ID":"611"},
 {"CUSTOMER_NAME":"MAD.","CUSTOMER_NO":"0000003133","CUSTOMER_SECTOR_ID":"611"}]
```

As you can see it is not same order. Do you have any idea to fix it ? I am using gson library.

Comment: As JSON objects do not inherently have an order, you should use an array within your JSON object to ensure order. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993645/ordered-jsonobject)

Comment: Thanks for your suggession @SergioMartinez but I can use your offered link if I know the type exactly. If I don't know it ? I just need to put strings as you see there is no field name. I am still trying to do but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jackson JSON Processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) saves order.
Simple example of usage:

```
   static ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
   {
      List<Map> array = new ArrayList<Map>();
      Map<String, String> obj1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
      obj1.put("CUSTOMER_SECTOR_ID", "Id");
      obj1.put("CUSTOMER_NO", "No");
      obj1.put("CUSTOMER_NAME", "Name");
      array.add(obj1);
      System.out.println(o.writeValueAsString(array));
   }
```

Maven dependency

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
     <version>1.8.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fields in a JSON objects don't have any order, because they are supposed to be accessed by their name (key).

If you need to keep an order, you have to use a JSON array instead.

I can't see why you would need named fields to be ordered, but if you really need to do so, you can use an array containing the fields of your JSON object.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993645/ordered-jsonobject) describes how to do so (thanks @SergioMartinez for the link, it saved me so much time!).

Comment: Yes I did exactly same as @SergioMartinez in javascript part, but in java I don't know where will it comes first. For example you try to create a datatable and in first field I am using checkbox and there must be id. But I can't be sure without ordering.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to read the JSON? You shouldn't be taking the *first field* but the **"CUSTOMER_SECTOR_ID" field**. That's the point of JSON field names, which are like keys in a map. If you need to display data in a table, then you have to know what the data look like, that includes the names of the fields.

Comment: But Customer_sector_id field will always be in change I bring it from another place. I will put Join fields to first object ob json so I can get with same order. I bring this json with user interaction.